# writing problems with MonoDevelop of Unity 3D

Tags: unity

MonoDevelop was automatically installed by UnityHub.
The text editor poses a lot of problems because you can not insert a specific character
(I position myself, the positioning is not famous and when I insert, it erases the following characters!)

Is there any way to fix this editing problem?
Or
should I install another version of MonoDevelop? If yes, I downloaded his msi file but after I do not know how to install it on my installed Unity

Thank you for your help

Comment: It's weird that UnityHub installed MonoDevelop at all. As far as I know, MonoDevelop is deprecated as a development environment for Unity for several years now and replaced by Visual Studio Community Edition. But regarding the problem at hand: Do you want to insert the character as part of a string literal? In that case there might be a workaround. Or is it an identifier? You really shouldn't use non-English characters in identifiers.

Comment: It sounds like you might be in overtype mode. Does your keyboard have an [Insert Key](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_key) you can try hitting to toggle the mode?